# M1 MacBook Pro Disable AutoBoot

Tags: macbook-pro, apple-silicon

Is there a way to disable autoboot on the M1 MacBook Pro? On recent MacBook Pro models the computer will start up automatically when opened (or then a key is pressed). With the Intel models it was possible to disable by setting a flag using the `nvram` command. This seems to no longer work on M1 Apple Silicon models.